# Conversions and calcs of float-types in Java

Tags: java, ieee-754

I was trying to really learn more about floats, doubles and bigdecimals in Java. I wanted to know exactly how a floating point number gets represented in each type, for ex. floats use 2^, big decimals use 10^ plus scaled(32-bit) and unscaled values (arbitrary precision).

I put together simple calcs using all three types and did conversations for each, the result is rather confusing. I would appreciate some hints about why the only correct representation is for float, and why when converted into Double and BigDecimal there were trailing imprecisions. Is it to do with binary representation conversions? Anyhow here are the code and its output:

```
    // Float - 32b
    float a = 3.14f;
    float b = 3.100004f;
    float abAsAFloat = a + b;
    double abAsADouble = a + b;
    BigDecimal abAsABigDecimal = new BigDecimal(a + b);

    System.out.println("a + b as a float: " + abAsAFloat);
    System.out.println("a + b as a double: " + abAsADouble);
    System.out.println("a + b as a BigDecimal: " + abAsABigDecimal);

    // Double - 64b
    double c = 3.14;
    double d = 3.100004;

    double cdAsADouble = c + d;
    BigDecimal cdAsABigDecimal = new BigDecimal(c + d);

    System.out.println("c + d as a double: " + cdAsADouble);
    System.out.println("c + d as a BigDecimal: " + cdAsABigDecimal);

    // BigDecimal, arbitrary-precision, signBit*unscaledValue × 10^-scale
    BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal(3.14);
    BigDecimal f = new BigDecimal(3.100004);

    BigDecimal efAsABigDecimal = e.add(f);

    System.out.println("e + f: " + efAsABigDecimal);

    // Drawbacks. speed, memory, native value equality, no overloads for +/- et al
```

> a + b as a float: 6.240004
>
> a + b as a double: 6.240004062652588
>
> a + b as a BigDecimal: 6.240004062652587890625
>
> c + d as a double: 6.240004000000001
>
> c + d as a BigDecimal:
>   6.2400040000000007722746886429376900196075439453125
>
> e + f: 6.240004000000000328185478792875073850154876708984375

Comment: These are representation errors are not random errors. You should always get the same results. BigDecimal also gets representation errors.

Comment: I guess it is from converting binary fractions to decimal number representation. To fully understand that you should get familiar how the [floating number is stored in memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

Answer (score 0):

`float` may look correct for this *particular case*, but it will be just as wrong for other values.  Note that when `float` and `double` are converted to strings, only as many digits are printed as are necessary to get the right value *in that type*; this means `float` may print "the correct answer" even when that representation conceals just as much rounding error as `double`.

The problem with `BigDecimal` is that you're not using it correctly: you should be writing `new BigDecimal("3.14")` instead of `new BigDecimal(3.14)`, which allows `double` to "mess it up" before `BigDecimal` has the chance to "fix it."

For the details of representation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format has a thorough explanation with useful diagrams, but the short explanation is that `float` and `double` represent numbers as +/- 1 * 1. * 2^, where `float` stores the mantissa with 22 bits and the exponent with 8 bits, and `double` uses 52 and 11 bits respectively.

Comment: Even if you have a `double` to start with, the docs for `BigDecimal` mention that you should use [`BigDecimal.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) instead of `new BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

You're inadvertently mixing types. For example:

```
BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal(3.14);
BigDecimal f = new BigDecimal(3.100004);
```

In this case, you're providing doubles as inputs, so e and f will have double residues. Instead, use this:

```
BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal("3.14");
BigDecimal f = new BigDecimal("3.100004");
```

The float output is seemingly the most accurate because Java "knows" floats have a limited precision, so it won't print fifteen digits.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert to either `double` or `BigDecimal` it converts to the closest representable value.  When you convert to BigDecimal you are actually converting to `double` first as there is no direct conversion from `float`.

Usually the you want to convert from `double` to BigDecimal using `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` This method assumes a certain level of rounding to match what the double would look like if you printed it.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Java Language Specification. Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Especially, **5.6. Numeric Promotions**

i.e

```
float a = 3.14f;
float b = 3.100004f;

double abAsADouble = a + b;
```

in this case first a will be added to b, giving a `float` result, then `float` will be converted to `double` and assigned. So, it might have a loss of precision, when comparing to `(double)a + b`;

The same thing, when using sum result as parameter to the constructor

```
new BigDecimal(a + b)
```

first, `float a` added to `float b`, giving a `float` result, after that it is converted to double and then BigDecimal object begins being constructed.

Any numeric constants with decimal point, unless you specify `f` at the end, are considered to be a `double`, so, when passing constant to the constructor:

new BigDecimal(3.100004);

Number is stored as `double` and passed as `double` precision to the constructor. To achieve more precision, use `String` parameter constructor instead:

new BigDecimal("3.100004");